# Can Google Maps be set to a slow constant pan? Like a globe revolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, panning

Just what the title says. I am searching for a solution but I have not found anything that has guided me to the correct documentation or articles.

If you have any ideas or can point me to a possible solution I can work with, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this yourself like this:

- Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) to set up a function to be run periodically.
- The function would call [`panBy`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) on the Google map object to "rotate" it a bit.

That should give you a simple animation that does what you want. You'd want to adjust the time interval that you give to `setInterval` to get something that feels smooth of course. You should have something like this:

```
// Create your map and leave it in the "map" variable.
setInterval(function() {
    map.panBy(x, 0);
}, n);
```

Choosing appropriate `x` and `n` values is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is ok, but a little outdated. Instead of `window.setInterval` you shoud use `window.requestAnimationFrame`. This will give you a smoother animation.

A simple example (not from me) can be found [here](http://codepen.io/j4k/pen/wMJEeB/), but the gist of it looks something like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my-map'), mapOptions)
function animate () {
  map.panBy(2.5 / 2, 1.3 / 2)
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    animate()
  })
}
// eslint-disable-next-line
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "tilesLoaded", function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    animate()
  })
})
window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
  animate()
})
```