# Animation between 2 points on Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to have a map with a list of markers on it. It needs to transition between these smoothly.

I have the following code which currently loops around the markers.

```
var x = 0;
function pan_to() {

    if(x >= addresses.length){
        x=0;
    }
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

        map.panTo(latlng);

    });
    x++;

} setInterval(pan_to,3000);
```

Working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/shanejones/khX2K/

What I need is the map to smoothly transition for 1 seconds between them with some form of easing too. Anyone have any ideas

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Its a perfectly valid question. +1

Comment: Pretty much why I rarely come here now... :(

Comment: Just noticed your Jsfiddle doesn't show a result, maybe fixing that would be a good idea? ;)

Comment: Sorted. The MapsAPI dropped out the fiddle settings for some reason.

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khX2K/2/) (at least shows the map, the API wasn't included).  Update, just saw your response, you have to make sure to do an "update" after making any changes or they go away.

Comment: You have missing semicolons on lines 15 and 31... try using the JShint tool in JSfiddle and it will display errors in your code :)

Comment: possibly relevant question [Google Maps v3 - can I ensure smooth panning every time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817812/google-maps-v3-can-i-ensure-smooth-panning-every-time)