# Google Maps JS API: move map animated between locations

Tags: jquery, google-maps, animation

I'm looking for some sample code (in the context of Google Maps) that

1. periodically checks my server database, to see if there is a new location that differs from the currently known location. I think I've found a solution direction [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), so the core of my question is:
2. in my browser, moves the center of the Google Map from the last know location to the now current location in a smooth, animated way.

I have found a similar dead-end question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536287/animation-between-2-points-on-google-maps), suggesting that this is a fishy kind of question to ask, but I try nevertheless.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the map to a new center just by using this code:

```
map.setCenter(newCenter:LatLng) OR
map.panTo(newCenter:LatLng)
```

if the distance between two LatLng objects be small enough, it moves smoothly by itself, otherwise you should wait for map tiles to be loaded for the new center location.

Comment: Hm, thanks, that looks as if I could have found that easily. Trying right now

Comment: setCenter is moving to position without animation.